# Github connection with ssh fail because of bad name resolution

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have registered an ssh key with my github account.
The keys are in

```
~/.ssh/id_rsa_github_snail
~/.ssh/id_rsa_github_snail.pub
```

I have a repo wherein the remote url is configured to use ssh:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:danielsank/pong.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:danielsank/pong.git (push)
```

However, when I try to push from a company computer, I get the following error message

```
danielsank@snail:~/src/pong$ git push
ssh: connect to host github.com.<company>.<name>.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Notice that ssh is, for some reason, trying to connect to `github.com.<company>.<name>.com` instead of `github.com`.

I have discovered the following suspicious bit in `/etc/resolve.conf`:

```
# It is common within <company> to lookup hostnames with a dot in it like for an
# example '<machine>.<site>'. We set 'options ndots:2' so that such hostnames
# get tried first with the <company> search domains appended. Without this such
# queries might be tried first against an external DNS resolver.
options ndots:2
```

I *can* ping github.com.

I tried setting the url to `git@github.com.:danielsank/pong.git`.
After doing that, when I try to push, I get asked to accept a host fingerprint from github, but then get a different error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

which I imagine is happening because of the extra dot in the repo name.

Is there a good way to work around this configuration?
I'm kinda surprised that the resolution doesn't try again without appending the company name...

---

Comment: What is in your `/etc/resolv.conf`? Can you just `ping github.com`? Try `ping github.com.` (note trailing dot). Try changing `origin` to `git@github.com.:danielsank/pong.git` (again, note the added dot).

Comment: Does the https version work? `https://github.com/danielsank/pong.git`

Comment: @Trolleymusic presently no, because I have 2-factor enabled on my github account (which is what started this whole thing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have strange DNS settings in `/etc/resolve.conf` or in a company's nameserver. To prevent these DNS settings to append `.<company>.<name>.com` to host names with a dot append a dot at the end of host names:

```
ping github.com. # <- note the dot!
git remote set-url origin git@github.com.:danielsank/pong.git
```

About the second problem — if you want to use a key with nonstandard name, as you have, you can assign keys to hosts in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host github.com github.com.
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github_snail
```

Comment: Merged 2 answers.